# Laplace, Correct Use of the Second Shift Theorem

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification

I have invested some time now trying to understand how to use the Second Shift Theorem, mostly by doing the full integration first.  What threw me off at first, I discovered, is that almost all books use the same dummy variable. Now I just want to know if the following method is fully correct, or if you would suggests improvements or point out misunderstandings:

$f(t)=\begin{cases}0 & 0 \leq t <2 \\ e^{at} & t \geq2 \end{cases}$

$\implies $

$\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\mathcal{L}[u_2(t)(e^{a(t-2)})]$

Let $\tau=t-2$ and use Second Shift Theorem:

$\implies$

$=e^{-2s}\mathcal{L}[e^{a \tau}]=e^{-2s}\mathcal{L}[e^{a(t-2)}]=e^{-2s}e^{2a}\mathcal{L}[e^{at}]=e^{-2(s-a)}\frac{1}{s-a}$

I cannot shake off the feeling that I am taking a detour here somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do Laplace transforms, I find it easier and more rewarding to just integrate then to remember all the theorems. Additionally, solving the problem via the definition usually helps me obtain a better understanding of what is actually going on. 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} & = \int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&= \int_0^20\cdot e^{-st}dt + \int_2^{\infty}e^{t(a-s)}dt\\
&=\int_2^{\infty}e^{t(a-s)}dt\tag{1}\\
&= -\frac{e^{-t(s-a)}}{s-a}\biggl|_2^{\infty}\tag{2}\\
&= \frac{e^{-2(s-a)}}{s-a}
\end{align}
In equation $(2)$, I pulled out a negative sign. Since in order for equation $(1)$ to converge, we need $t(a-s)<0\iff a<s$. Therefore, $a-s$ is already a negative quantity so let's write $-t(s-a)$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will just do that myself too!

Comment: @Akitirija plus when it comes down to test time, you don't have to stress about memorizing every Laplace transform in the table plus X different theorems.

Comment: Might I also add that seing your solution of the problem gave me more than any textbook so far...

Comment: @Akitirija I think most undergraduate ODE textbooks gloss over this stuff since the books are usually focused on math and engineering students.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the impression that I have too...